# Violin string G not playing smoothly

Tags: violin, sound, tone

Whenever I play my violin (beginner) I always find that the G string doesn’t play well and is very choppy and dull while the other strings are fine. I have tuned it multiple times to try and get it to work. Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Playing on the G string, you need to press moderately to make it sound good. If the problem does not get resolved, have you tried replacing the string?

Answer (score 0):

The amount of stress applied onto the string will have a large influence on whether the sound produced is smooth or not, and the G string is especially tricky for beginners to control in my opinion. You can practice playing the G string at different tempo and strength, and find out the suitable stress for you. Also remember that you would need less stress at the frogs end of the bow than that of the tips, so the stress would vary when you play at different part of the bow.

Secondly, whether the string is tuned or not doesn't play a big role in the quality of sound so it is not necessary to constantly tune the violin. What you need is to practice more and the sound will improve.